# Why isn't my Vscode running my simple program and how can I fix it?

Tags: c

My code should be way simple yet whenever I run it I get this :

```
c:\Users\<MyLaptop'sname>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.15.4-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-tcoej3zt.jpf' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-mgt55pxk.t32' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-irnbbu1z.cvb' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-4hc4rdjl.5xd' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
```

and the program doesn't even ask for an input

I got an assignment in 5 days and not even my IDE is working. I wouldn't mind other IDE's suggestions in case this won't work cuz I been trying for a while

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

  int i, j, n, mat[n][n];
  printf("Enter the size of the matrix: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter the elements of the matrix: ");
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for (i= 0 ; i < n ;i++){
    for (j=0; j< n;j++)
    {
      printf("%d", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("  ");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I was trying to just run this code to test my Vscode after it went mad and stopped compiling or running code.

Comment: You can't do `int mat[n][n]` before reading `n` from user input, C code doesn't work like a spreadsheet. The value of `n` is undetermined when you declare the matrix. If `n` happens to be a massively large number it's possible you're blowing up your stack before you even get to user input,, no clue what happens if it's negative.

Comment: ..so move `int mat[n][n];` after the `scanf` line, as well as fully validating what `scanf("%d", &n);` did (or didn't).

Comment: There is another problem with `for (i=0; i<n; i++) { for (j=0; j<n; j++)` because the code has not input values for every element (unless `n == 2`). Printing uninitialised values is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: If your IDE does not work, you can try running your code online at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ or https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Since you have no time to tinker with a non-working IDE, don't. Uninstall vscode. Edit your program with notepad++, compile and run by typing commands in cmd or another shell.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "stopped compiling or running code." Compiling and running your code are 2 very different steps. They have different reasons to fail. Therefore you should always include a proper description of your problem. Please keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

your program won't compile because the array mat has the size n*n, and n is not initialised at this point. if you declare the array after you ask the user for n, it should compile.